# Does aws support software (not hsm) keys for cheap key storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

Google cloud supports a [Software backed key storage](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/algorithms#protection_levels) where the key price is 6 cents compared to a 1 euro hsm.

For solutions like crypto shredding where one wants to have a key per subject/person, a hsm key can be quite a costly.

Extra security could be added by key wrapping on top of the software keys, i believe.

Answer (score 1):

From [AWS Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html):

> AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) is a managed service that makes it easy for you to create and control the cryptographic keys that are used to protect your data.

[Pricing | AWS Key Management Service (KMS) | Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/pricing/) is $1/month per KMS key.

When you want to use one key per subject/person, the technique is normally:

- Generate a random symmetric encryption key and encrypt the subject/person/object
- Encrypt that key with a KMS key
- Store the encrypted key with the encrypted object

This means that you only need to generate a single KMS key, yet every object is encrypted with a different key.

For more information, see: [AWS KMS concepts - AWS Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#symmetric-cmks)

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply.


I have seen your suggested approach and its support even on known libraries as google tink.

However, in the context of cryptoshredding, it would be important the ability of forget the subject, by throwing its key away. Having it stored along the (several) encrypted objects miss that point.